# What’s the etymology of “beholden”?

Tags: etymology, derivational-morphology

I know the word *behold* means to look upon. So why does *beholden* mean obligated, indebted?

Can someone tell me how this phrase came about?

Comment: [etymonline gives little which probably means there is probably little](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=beholden)

Comment: Etymology From Middle English beholden, from Old English behealdan (“to hold, have, occupy, possess, guard, preserve, contain, belong, keep, observe, consider, behold, look at, gaze on, see, signify, avail, effect, take care, beware, be cautious, restrain, act, behave”), from Proto-Germanic *bihaldanan (“to hold with, keep”), equivalent to be- +‎ hold. Cognate with Dutch behouden (“to keep, restrain, preserve”), German behalten (“to keep, restrain, remember”), Danish and Norwegian beholde (“to keep”) and Swedish behålla (“to keep”). http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/behold

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Origin:

> " 1300–50; Middle English,  adj. use of beholden,  old past
>   participle of behold"
>
> "under obligation," mid-14c., originally pp. of behold (and
>   preserving the
>    original pp. of hold), but this sense is not recorded among the many
>   and varied
>   senses   attested for behold .

Comment: If you are quoting something, it might be helpful to say what. Perhaps it came from [here](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/beholden)

Comment: @Henry: [Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=beholden) as well.

Comment: As Henry. Cite the source.

Answer (score 1):

We hold objects in our gazes, we hold others to their debts.  The sense of holding is the same, though the subjects we are holding vary.

Comment: Opinion, maybe?

Answer (score -1):

The OED says for "behold":

†1.

a. *trans*. To hold by, keep hold of, retain. *Obs*.

and

†2. *trans*. To hold by some tie of duty or obligation, to retain as a client or person in duty bound. Found only in the pa. pple. BEHOLDEN *adj*., q.v.

(and other meanings, of course).

It gives examples of the first up to 1525, and no examples of the second.